# Can vibration damage a HDD that is powered off?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I've heard that vibration can damage a HDD.  If a drive is turned off while it experiences vibration, is it still likely to be damaged?

I was moving my desk a while ago and it had to be dragged across the floor due to its weight. Unfortunately my external HDD (WD My Book 4TB) was on the desk, powered off, during the move.

The HDD appears to work properly, but I wonder if the vibrations may have caused some hidden damage that will show up over time, or reduced the drive's lifespan.

Comment: dazzbee, your title does not match the content of your post. A HDD that falls off the desk is exposed to a shock that can be measured in the acceleration unit "g". Vibration would take place when a vibrating HDD is transfer its vibrations to a dormant one for instance. Shock is a different symptom than vibration.

Comment: If you still can, I'd copy (best clone using ddrescue or similar) data to a different drive and discard the one that fell to the floor. Don't push your luck.

Comment: im so sorry if you guys misunderstood with my question due to my bad english (im not native english speaker) , the hdd not falling off from the table , the 'off' literally the hdd not connected to computer or in off condition, i was concerned about the vibration that cause by dragging my desk ( i was moving my desk position)

Comment: Okay, well vibration is less likely to damage an unpowered not in use drive than damaging an in use drive. But no one can give you any guarantees. But I think you're fine.

Comment: thanks for insight glad to hear it less likely to damage my hdd

Comment: @r2d3 I have restored (edited for grammar and spelling) the author's [original post](https://superuser.com/revisions/1787975/1) whose meaning had been changed significantly through community edits.

Comment: @dazzbee Welcome to Super User and Stack Exchange! Thank you for taking the time to clarify your question in the comments.  You may not be a native English speaker,  but your communication skills are excellent. I hope you will continue to take part in this community, asking questions and helping others where you can. The community edits questions and answers in an effort to make them better, but we sometimes get it wrong.  Your comment clarified your intent, which allowed us to get it right.

Comment: By asking "*can* vibration damage a HDD" you make it difficult for anyone to answer "no."  Even something that is "highly unlikely" to happen, such as being struck by lightning, *can* still happen. @JoepvanSteen gave a [good answer](https://superuser.com/a/1788023) especially pointing out the core issue, that regardless of whether this incident impacted your drive's lifespan, it does indeed have a lifespan.  It's *likely* to last a long time, but *may* also fail at any time.  Therefore, important data should always be backed up.

Comment: @BlindSpots thank you for the correction very much appreciate it.

Comment: my floor very much flat a bit uneven but not noticable there is no bump /jolt etc  (ceramic tile floor) , my desk was bit too heavy (large table from wood) i moved the desk by myself and i just realized this is mistake to move it by myself..it was bit awkward and i was noticed i made lot of vibration during dragging my table , my hdd wasn't falling off and unpowered but the vibration made me worried it would cause any damage

Comment: @dazzbee Thank you! Please edit your question to include all relevant information.  This way future visitors and people currently trying to answer it can get all the relevant information right in the question without needing to read everyone's comments.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you mean heads slamming into the platter surface due to shock or vibration while the drive is in use. This is indeed a serious risk.

If the drive wasn't powered at the time of the vibrations/shocks the heads were in a parked position, most likely away from the drive's surface, and you're probably okay.

No one can give guarantees though, and eventually all drives will die. Make sure you have a backup.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps of interest, this is a 2007 HGST Whitepaper from Western Digital's website (WD bought HGST in 2012):  [Ramp Load/Unload  Technology in  Hard Disk Drives](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/collateral/white-paper/loadunload-white-paper-final.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, saved it!

Comment: thanks for insight and thanks for the pic didn't know there is this kind mechanism inside the hdd ..yes my external hdd wasn't powered during the shock and vibration glad to hear it will probably okay